# How to send an email if there are any changes in the sharepoint list using power automate?

Tags: power-automate

My flow is as follows:

[image]

The condition which I have set after "Get changes" is as follows:

```
"expression": {
    "or": [
      {
        "equals": [
          "@body('Get_changes_for_an_item_or_a_file_(properties_only)')?['ColumnHasChanged']?['Links']",
          true
        ]
      },
      {
        "equals": [
          "@body('Get_changes_for_an_item_or_a_file_(properties_only)')?['ColumnHasChanged']?['Modified']",
          true
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

When I try to test the flow it always returns true even though no modification has been done.
How to correct the conditions?

My SharePoint list does not have a 'Modified' column as such, I am guessing it is an inbuilt column for each item in the SharePoint list which gets updated when a change is triggered.

So I need help to correct these conditions. I want the flow to send an email only if there is a change. So that is why I have initialized a variable that is set to "true" when the condition is satisfied.

Comment: What's the trigger that you're using?

Comment: Recurrence trigger. It runs after 2 weeks and gets the items. And if there is a change in the SharePoint list then it should send an email.

Comment: Yes, the `Modified` column is the date that is updated each time the item is changed.  When the item is created, it's populated with the creation date but through that operation, it will only be set to `true` after the item is truly modified.

Comment: What parameters are you passing into the get changes operation?